# Best workarounds for deleting or modifying an (not necessarily at top) element in std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

There are several posts on deletions and modifications of keys in a `std::priority_queue`, but some of these posts are from a decade ago.

I am wondering if there's any recent changes (maybe in the past 5 years or so) that would allow easier deletion or modification of a `std::priority_queue`? The way I see it is, really it's just the deletion that it's needed because you can turn a modification of a key into two steps (deletion + insertion).

Comment: No, there has been no recent change to `priority_queue` that makes it easier to do what you want, and none are expected. `std::priority_queue` is a container adaptor implementing a heap, which is not an efficient data structure for removing elements that aren't at the front of the queuet. You need a different data structure, maybe a sorted vector.

Comment: @user4581301 Unfortunately, this is for a programming competition, and I don't really have any other choices.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux When I studied heaps and priority queues (e.g., in CLRS's Intro to Algorithms), there's always an implementation for modifying keys and deleting keys. In practice, is that just not really used very often?

Comment: @user5965026 I think you may be thinking of a binary tree which is more generic. See `std::set` and `std::map`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No I'm thinking of heaps (e.g., chapter 6.5 of CLRS provides a function `INCREASE-KEY.S`.)

Comment: The competition probably just want to figure out if you are smart enough to pop items into another container until you find the one to remove and then add them again.

Comment: @user5965026 You can then use heap functions in C++ (for ex. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/) but then you are not using a `priority_queue`.

Comment: @Phil1970 cplusplus.com has a reputation for containing errors and terrible examples. I'm not sure if this is true anymore (though it was warranted at one point) but in any case cppreference.com is widely regarded as a more trustworthy source for C++ and the reference of choice the Stack Overflow's C++ tag. In the future, I would recommend posting links to cppreference.com instead of cplusplus.com. For `std::make_heap` that would be https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well cplusplus put C++ reference in its title so one has to be very careful... And since Google almost always put an ads as first result, I tend to check second result first.